# Small rotation brings Openlayers map to original position. How to disable this effect?

Tags: rotation, openlayers

If I rotate the OpenLayers map (Alt+Shift+Drag by default) by a very small amount and release the mouse, the map rotates back to its original position.

This is default behavior and you can see it [here](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/bing-maps.html).

How this effect is called and how can I disable it?

Answer (score 1):

Use [constrainRotation](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.View.html) option for that

> Rotation constraint. false means no constraint. true means no
>   constraint, but snap to zero near zero. A number constrains the
>   rotation to that number of values. For example, 4 will constrain the
>   rotation to 0, 90, 180, and 270 degrees. The default is true.